# Grab Server Code on refresh every few seconds and update form elements

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

To start off here's how the application works: (note: there are multiple users on the page like Patient M, Patient E, so on)

1) Next to Patient X's name is a button labeled **Check In**. This is logged in the server side.

2) Upon clicking the **Check In** button , the user is then presented with a dropdown (replacing the initial button) with the multiple locations the user could choose. Upon selecting a location from the select, the server side is updated again.

3) The user then might decide to choose multiple locations, repeating step 2

4) At the end, when the user is done selecting locations, he clicks on the **Check Out button** in the same select where the user had clicked locations in steps 2 and 3, titled Check Out. Upon clicking this, it is sent to checkloc.php and logged.

5) Finally, the dropdown dissapears and the words Checked Out appear.

Unfortunately, the problem is that right now if I am Computer 1, and go through the process of clicking Check In, selecting a location, and checking out, this is completely apart from Computer 2 doing this.

Heres a diagram:

[image: what I want to happen]

So basically I need a way to grab the server code every few seconds and update the form elements with the current values. I'm a pretty new programmer, so code and tutorials would be extra helpful. Also, like I just mentioned, I am a new programmer, so if my code could be cleaned up in any ways that would be fantastic.

Thanks for any and all help! I'm glad to clarify any questions you have!

Heres the code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.locationSelect').hide();  // Hide all Selects on screen
$('.finished').hide();        // Hide all checked Out divs on screen
$('.checkOut').hide();

$('.checkIn').click(function() {
    var $e = $(this);
    var data = $e.data("param").split('_')[1] ;
    // gets the id  of button
    // You can map this to the corresponding button in database...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkin.php",
        // Data used to set the values in Database
        data: { "checkIn" : $(this).val(), "buttonId" : data},
        success: function() {
            // Hide the current Button clicked
            $e.hide();
            // Get the immediate form for the button
            // find the select inside it and show...
            $('.locationSelect').show();
            $('.checkOut').show();
        }
    });
});

$('.locationSelect').change(function() {
    $e = $(this);
    var data = $e.data("param").split('_')[1] ;
    // gets the id  of select
    // You can map this to the corresponding select in database...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "changeloc.php",
        data: { "locationSelect" : $(this).val(), "selectid" : data},
        success: function() {
            // Do something here
        }
    });
});

$('.checkOut').click(function() {
    var $e = $(this);
    var data = $e.data("param").split('_')[1] ;
    // gets the id  of button
    // You can map this to the corresponding button in database...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkout.php",
        // Data used to set the values in Database
        data: { "checkOut" : $(this).val(), "buttonId" : data},
        success: function() {
            // Hide the current Button clicked
            $e.hide();
            $('.locationSelect').hide();
            // Get the immediate form for the button
            // find the select inside it and show...
            $('.finished').show();
        }
    });
});

});
</script>
```

and html:

```
<button class="checkIn" data-param="button_9A6D43BE-D976-11D3-B046-00C04F49F230">Check In</button>

<form method='post' class='myForm' action=''>
  <select name='locationSelect' class='locationSelect' data-param="location_9A6D43BE-D976-11D3-B046-00C04F49F230">
    <option value="0">Select a location</option>
    <option value='1'>Exam Room 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Exam Room 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Exam Room 3</option>
    <option value='4'>Exam Room 4</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button class="checkOut" data-param="cbutton_9A6D43BE-D976-11D3-B046-00C04F49F230">Check Out</button>

<div class='finished' style='color:#ff0000;'>Checked Out</div>
```

heres the server side code ( I split it into three pages just for testing)

checkin.php

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');

$apptid = $_REQUEST['buttonId'];
$currentlocationstart = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

if(isset($_REQUEST['checkIn'])){
    $checkin = 0;
}


$hostname = 'localhost';

$username = '*******';

$password = '******';


$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=sv", $username, $password);

$sql = "UPDATE schedule SET currentlocation = ?, currentlocationstart = ? WHERE apptid= ? ";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($checkin,$currentlocationstart, $apptid));


?>
```

locationchange.php

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');

$apptid = $_REQUEST['selectId'];
$currentlocationstart = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

if(isset($_REQUEST['locationSelect'])){
    $currentLocation = $_REQUEST['locationSelect'];
}


$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = '*****';
$password = '*******';


$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=sv", $username, $password);

$sql = "UPDATE schedule SET currentlocation = ?, currentlocationstart = ? WHERE apptid= ? ";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($currentlocation,$currentlocationstart, $apptid));

?>
```

and checkout.php

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');

$apptid = $_REQUEST['buttonId'];
$currentlocationstart = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

if(isset($_REQUEST['checkOut'])){
    $checkin = 1000;
}


$hostname = 'localhost';

$username = '*********';

$password = '********';


$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=sv", $username, $password);

$sql = "UPDATE schedule SET currentlocation = ?, currentlocationstart = ? WHERE apptid= ? ";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($checkin,$currentlocationstart, $apptid));


?>
```

Comment: You have to move all logic is on the server. Whatever is going to happen, checked, shown have to be pulled from server. Your end user application have to be just dumb client to present the data. Not sure what else you want to discuss? Maybe you shall consider starting a bounty as this quite looks too localized to me

Comment: You must ask the question WHY do you want computer 2 to catch up with input on computer 1? think about it, someone sitting on computer 2, all of a sudden his screen displays location, freaky ain't it? what if user on computer 2 decided to be part of the action and choose a location before computer 1 gets to do that? this isn't logical, to go about this, first, describe the problem (not like what you did above, you described a solution you'd like implemented).

Comment: @Jake: Can you update the post with what you have server side so far?

Comment: @aam1r sure, just give me a sec

Comment: In order to do this, you'll need to set up a socket or a ajax-call that is executed every xx seconds. The script needs to connect to the database and return values/settings if anything is changed. Still, I don't get this question really. I see no point in doing this.

Comment: @Ayyash This is for a doctors application so there will be multiple doctor assistants looking at the same page, so one might hit a location and another doctor assistant would change from what the first doctor assistant did. Your comment is very helpful though, I should probably rephrase my question to not synchronize instantly, but be a refresh every x seconds that looks up server code

Comment: @OptimusCrime is there anything specific you don't understand about the question? I'm glad to help

Comment: @OptimusCrime I just googled AJAX Socket Jquery and started reading about that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jake on a side note, technically that solves the problem but logically? maybe you should visit ux.stackexchange.com and ask for opinions

Comment: Are you going to award the bounty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referring to a methodology known as a "heartbeat".  I am going to post an example here, but first I'd like to give you a few pointers since, as you said, you are a new dev :).

1) With JQuery, try to avoid using the class selector.  It's notoriously slow.  Use the id selector wherever possible, or the nodename selector with a narrowed search scope if it isn't possible.  The browser uses the ID as a sort of "index" or "key" to the dom element, so it is the fastest search.

2) PRELOAD!  Even if you are going to use class selectors, don't do

```
    $('.locationSelect')
```

Over and over.  If you are going to reference the same DOM element more than once, do this:

```
    var locationSelect = $('.locationSelect'); //this creates a reference
    $(locationSelect).whatever() //this uses the reference
```

By doing this, you are only searching the DOM once.  It won't seem like a big deal with smaller apps, but as your app becomes more and more complicated, it takes more and more time to search to DOM for elements.  By using a reference, you only search once.

3) (Optional) I would RECOMMEND using an MVC platform like AngularJS (which is written by Google).  MVC, or Model View Controller, allows you to update a "Model" (basically a JavaScript Object) and the "View" (the HTML) automatically adjusts its value using something called UI-Bindings.  It's a great way to go about developing an app from the get-go, but if you are already knee-deep in plain-jane code, it may not be practical for you.  I'd still take a look at their tutorial to see what it could offer you: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/

Now on to your original question!  Yes, this is completely possible with jQuery by using a methodology known as a heartbeat.  A heartbeat allows you to emulate data persistence between the server and client.  The more frequent the heartbeat, the more in-sync your clients will be, but the greater load on your webserver as well.  It's a balancing act.
In a nutshell, it works something like this:

```
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: 'heartbeatscript.php',
           method: 'post'
           //whatever data you want to send
        }).done(function(data){
           //do whatever with the returned result
        });
    },heartbeatInterval); //heartbeatInterval will be however many MS you want
```

I would also recommend using JSON to communicate between the client and server.  JSON is easy to parse on both ends, and on the client end it is simply the fastest mechanism for parsing bulk data.  JSON is parsed directly into a JavaScript object because the notation is literally what JS uses to store object Data within the browser anyway.  XML is also a good choice.  Both are very easy to get started with:

Client Side:
You can use jQuery to parse rudimentary XML:

```
    $('nodeName',xml);
```

You can parse JSON into a JSO like this:

```
    var JSO = JSON.parse(JSONString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the tips about class selectors and heartbeats were super helpful! I'll look into this and get back to you.

Comment: If you found it useful, rep points would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), because as the site says:

> ### What is Socket.IO?
>
> Socket.IO aims to make realtime apps possible in every browser and mobile device

Although Socket.IO is in NodeJS/Javascript, there's quite an conversation about [using PHP with Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398887/using-php-with-socket-io)

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the basic principles of a web application that every action is initiated at the client, i.e. if you want to change the display at one of the computers, someone would have to click something *on that computer*. Originally there was no possibility to update the display on the second computer if something happens on the server, and there is still no trivial solution.

However, with modern browsers [several technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) have been developed and are in widespread use among web mail clients and responsive "Web 2.0" applications. You would have to decide on one of them and implement them yourself, each of them having its pros and cons.

The one easiest to implement (apart from a simple "refresh" button) is probably to do an AJAX request every few seconds and update the screen according to the current user state that the server reports.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it seems what you are looking to do is to update data from one machine on another machine without the need to do a page reload.

It is good that you already have some familiarity with AJAX, as that will probably be one of the ways you can implement your solution.  What you are needing, in essence, is to poll the server from the webpages at some specified interval (maybe every second or every few seconds depending on your need).  You can do this using AJAX.

When you poll this server, you can pull down data (HTML fragments, JSON data, whatever makes sense in your application) and use this data to update the page. So when a user makes an update on Computer 1, Computer 2 will be able to poll the server and pull in updates related to the data changes on Computer 1.