# Architecture for realtime website.... PHP5 Angularjs and android MQTT

Tags: angularjs, architecture, mosquitto, broker

I'm trying to make a realtime website with an android client. How does one connect eg mosquitto to PHP5, angularjs frontend and the android app?

Do I have to use nodeJs with socket.io for the angularjs frontend and then nodeJs server for all android MQTT messages?

This is all so confusing. I tried for a while with rabbit but got stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

If your android app needs to send messages to server only, you could use simple REST API. If you need server to the application messaging too, then you could try [Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) or just use simple WebSockets, which can give you real time performance. In the latter case you need Java implementation of WebSockets client, for instance, [this one](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket).

Realtime communication between the server and browser can be done using WebSockets too. You can use one of numerous PHP WebSockets implementation like [this](https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php). Using Socket.IO could be a bit tricky, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398887/using-php-with-socket-io) to get more information.

In browser you can use standard [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications). If you have requirements to support old browsers, which have no WebSockets support, then you need to check Socket.IO or SockJS library because they provide fallback mechanism.

Comment: This won't work. There needs to be a message broker to publish the messages and for all the clients to subscribe to this broker.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna answering to it if anyone is still stuck (6 years later)

> Do I have to use nodeJs with socket.io for the angularjs frontend and then nodeJs server for all android MQTT messages?

That's the idea.

1. Install a broker on your server (mosquitto works well with nodejs)
   a. add a first listener using mqtt protocol in your broker conf
   b. add a second listener for websocket protocol
2. Connect your android client (the publisher) to your broker using the mqtt protocol
3. Connect your website (the suscriber) using websocket protocol (https://github.com/php-mqtt/client for php)

The idea is to use the mqtt protocol as it suited for embedded devices messaging (lighter => faster, more reliable). The websocket protocol would be used as it is made for communication btw websites and servers.