# How to generate real time notification system like facebook in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, redis, socket.io

I want to create a real time notification system for my website(social network)
I'm using laravel 5.2,
I am using socket.io and redis currently,
I have created notifevent and broadcasted it succesfully, but no idea what to do ahead, can anyone please help me with it or guide me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You should have a `NodeJS` and `socket.io`, install it on your server
2. When have event, use `Redis` to hold your variable and send it to your `NodeJs` or Use this PHP Library, you can send variable from `PHP` to `NodeJS` Server: http://elephant.io/
3. Data Processing on the `NodeJs`
4. Return it to PHP Webpage use `Socket.io (client javascript)` to catch this event and display for end-user (using `emit` and `on`)

You can follow this instruction with `elephant.io`: [Using PHP with Socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398887/using-php-with-socket-io)

or that with `Redis`: https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-Redis-and-Socket.io

You should try two ways and feedback with new question if you stuck because your question is unclear and very hard to answer

You can use `javascript` send Ajax Request and get variable from `PHP` and use this variable to make a `socket.emit` but this way is less security, you must use `token` or anything like this if you want to public your website