# Use Meteor reactivity in simple PHP+HTML+JS based website

Tags: meteor

Is there any way to use Meteor reactivity in a simple PHP+HTML+JS based website?

I have a Meteor based App for news feeds, I have published these news feeds reactivily and I want to show these news feeds reactivily on one of my another site that is based on simple PHP, HTML & Javascript.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just drop your Meteor news feeds into an iframe in your main site? The alternatives are not pretty.

Comment: No way I am doing it this way, I need a proper implementation. Like adding some meteor library script or something

Comment: Meteor is much more than you need for reactivity and will never be *simple* as an add-on to a PHP site. Look at socket.io instead - see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398887/using-php-with-socket-io

Comment: Publish your news feed as json using some reat api package and in php site fetch them using ajax or curl.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Actually I need much more from Meteor App, so Implementing socket.io is not feasible for me at this point. And I am sure that there will be some script like android DDP or IOS Swift DDP for web aswell