# reloading page when new message recieve by the user not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

Reloading page when new message received by the user not working.

I am developing a PHP chat application. Where admin and users can chat.

When new message arises, the user needs to reload the page and fetch the new message from the database.

My query is:-

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `chat` 
    WHERE fromthe = '$email' and tothe='theadmin' 
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `chat`
    WHERE fromthe = 'theadmin' and tothe='$email' order by id desc";   
$sql1 = "UPDATE `chat` SET `status`='1' where tothe='$email'";
         mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
```

Please help me to do it.

Thanks

Comment: What's the error you're getting? How is it not working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398887/using-php-with-socket-io

Comment: the ajax is not reloading the page after working the mysql query

Comment: @fazalza and that what i told you in my answear , you can either hit the dabatase every x second or use websocket , your javascript will have no idea when another user post a new message into the database

Comment: Where's the code to reload something?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `setInterval` and hit the database every x second to check for new message wish is a really bad practice , or use websocket

Comment: i have tried a lot.. but not worked.. will you do it for me ?

Comment: @fazalza include your code using websocket and if you have any issue i will help you