# How to display realtime records from database using codeigniter

Tags: javascript

How do I write a JavaScript code such that when there is an increase in the value of an input type="text", it should do something.

I fetch a count of database table row into the input, so I want it to alert when there is a change/increase in that value. Thanks

Comment: Question is far too broad per guidelines in the [help]. Do some research into form control events and using ajax

Comment: A little knowledge of the React.js library might help as well.

Comment: I have an ajax query that takes care of the input value. All I want is a simple JavaScript code that hold that value in a global variable, such that when the value changes, it should alert the new value and store it in the global variable

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it - using [sockets](https://socket.io/).
Logic something like that: on event that modify counter you should "emit" value to frontend. Frontend catch new value and update DOM.
Here is example of server side part: [Using PHP with Socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398887/using-php-with-socket-io)