# How to trigger some event from Admin Panel to some user specific page in PHP (core PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, admin

So I got a requirement to create a polling system which is to be same as zoom poll. The idea is to completely replace zoom polling system with our code.

The company wants to show the polling screen only when they trigger from the admin panel.

So, I have to trigger the poll from the admin panel to some specific page of users. The poll will be triggered as a popup to the user screen.

Any hint can help me to work on it. But, I just couldn't find the best way to do it that's why I am here for some help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to send a message from a PHP server to a PHP page open in the client's browser?

Comment: It's not a message but basically it's too much same.
I need to show a popup to the client's browser and that in real time when admin wants to show the popup to the user.

Comment: Sending a real-time message to a PHP client is not easy; there's no ready-made solution for this because people who want to be able to do that usually don't pick PHP for their backend. See here for reference, but be aware of the fact that the question and answers are pretty old: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398887/using-php-with-socket-io

Comment: A workaround is to put the poll in a queue server-side and have all clients repeatedly ping the server for a new poll (like every three seconds or so).

Comment: @ChrisG but it will repeatedly refresh every 3 seconds. There are polling system which have many question in it. If refreshing every 3 seconds then the form will get cleared every time it will refresh the div.

Comment: I didn't mean refresh the page, I meant use ajax/fetch to send a request in the background.